# Bootstrap - form elements auto layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have the following form, I want to have 3 items in a row.
Since it is auto generated I cant really change to much the html.
I cant have dynamic span for each column.
With the limitations I have here, is it possible to break the code bellow so Ill have 3 fields in a row?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/52VtD/446/

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden">
  <div class="span1">
    <label>
      Email Address
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="span1">
    <label>
      Full Name
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="FullName" name="FullName" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="span1">
    <label>
      Active?
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="span1">
    <label>
      Password
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" type="password">
  </div>
  <input name="Avatar.Id" type="hidden">
  <div class="span1">
    <label>
      Upload image
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="Avatar.FileContent" name="Avatar.FileContent" placeholder="Select an image" type="file">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, But I didn't got your Question. Can you please provide a fiddle instead of this Raw code.

Comment: Are you able to give the `.row-fluid` `div` an id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to break Bootstrap a lot, but if you could give the container an `id` and style it this way:

```
#form-container {
    width: 700px;
}

#form-container .row-fluid .span1 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

To get this result: http://fiddle.jshell.net/52VtD/448/

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it helps not over thinking Bootstrap.  Also note, this is Bootstrap 3 I'm using.

If you're looking to have "three items" in a row, including the labels, that can be created with 6 columns.  3 per label and 3 per input.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/pLSD9/1/

In this case, you don't use any of the built in form layouts like `.form-inline`.  You use the Bootstrap grid and place your elements in it accordingly.  Since Bootstrap gives it's form input elements 100% width, they'll fill the grid space.

I used the "sm" size grid so when the form gets to what Bootstrap considers a "small" size, it will stack the elements.  Since JSFiddle brings the page down into windows,you might have to adjust the window size to see the grid layout.

I hope that helps!
Cheers!